# How can I fix the Error handler for my Macro in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that has buttons that view a record based on where `[ID]=[Contact Name]`.
However,  when the rows are blank, and the button is clicked I receive the error

> Syntax error(missing operater)in query expression [id]

I am currently using the on click macro which opens the form to the condition:

```
 ="[ID]=" & [Contact Name]
```

I have attempted the on error method, however it still shows the standard MS Access error warning (*Syntax error(missing operater)in query expression [id]*) before showing mine which is "no contact in field"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvFVZ.png)

Comment: Could paste the code you're using please - (if the image is showing the code I'm afraid that's blocked here).  Pasting the actual code into the question allows others to copy it and paste it for testing.

Comment: The image does open. It shows macro code, not VBA. I don't use macros, only VBA so not familiar with error handler in macro. Use an If Then conditional to only execute form open if field has data. Or use LIKE and * wildcard so all records will return if [Contact Name] is empty.